# Bulk Query with PK Chunking enabled sometimes does not return all the batches

Tags: apex, rest-api, java, bulk-api

The requirement is to use Bulk Query API with PK Chunking enabled, and to create CVS files for each batch with the chunk-size
For example, in the Account Object if I have 80,000 records, and have the "chunk-size" as "2000", then I need to use the Bulk Query API with PK Chunking enabled, and create 40 CVS files( one for each batch) with 2000 records in each files.

Many a times it happens, that I get less then 40 batches read.

What am I missing here. Is there a check so that I can call "bulkConnection.getBatchInfoList() method" after all the batches have been created. I API method that I am using is

**BatchInfo[] bListInfo = bulkConnection.getBatchInfoList(job.getId()).getBatchInfo();**

Attached is the source code which I am running to accomplish this task

```
    public class BulkQueryPKChunking {


    public static void main(String[] args)
      throws AsyncApiException, ConnectionException, IOException {
        BulkQueryPKChunking exampleQuery = new BulkQueryPKChunking();
        System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
        BulkConnection bulkConnection = exampleQuery.login();
        bulkConnection.addHeader("Sforce-Enable-PKChunking","chunkSize=2000");
        exampleQuery.doBulkQuery(bulkConnection);
    }


    public BulkConnection login() {

          String userName = "deepnaik@ibm.com";
          String passWord = "DN2006ascPBmF0sqBPkVVCBp1ZmOhxhXQF";
          String url = "https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/32.0";
          BulkConnection _bulkConnection = null;
          try {

                ConnectorConfig partnerConfig = new ConnectorConfig();
                partnerConfig.setUsername(userName);
                partnerConfig.setPassword(passWord);
                partnerConfig.setAuthEndpoint(url);
                new PartnerConnection(partnerConfig);
                ConnectorConfig config = new ConnectorConfig();
                config.setSessionId(partnerConfig.getSessionId());
                String soapEndpoint = partnerConfig.getServiceEndpoint();
                String apiVersion = "32.0";
                String restEndpoint = soapEndpoint.substring(0, soapEndpoint.indexOf("Soap/"))
                    + "async/" + apiVersion;
                config.setRestEndpoint(restEndpoint);
                config.setCompression(true);
                config.setTraceMessage(false);
                _bulkConnection = new BulkConnection(config);
          } catch (AsyncApiException aae) {
            aae.printStackTrace();
          } catch (ConnectionException ce) {
            ce.printStackTrace();
          }
          return _bulkConnection;
        }



    public void doBulkQuery(BulkConnection bulkConnection) {

          try {
            JobInfo job = new JobInfo();
            job.setObject("Account");

            job.setOperation(OperationEnum.query);
            job.setConcurrencyMode(ConcurrencyMode.Parallel);
            job.setContentType(ContentType.CSV);

            job = bulkConnection.createJob(job);
            assert job.getId() != null;
            System.out.println("Job id is " + job.getId());

            job = bulkConnection.getJobStatus(job.getId());

            String query = "SELECT Name, Id FROM Account";
            ByteArrayInputStream bout = new ByteArrayInputStream(query.getBytes()); 
            bulkConnection.createBatchFromStream(job, bout);             
            bulkConnection.closeJob(job.getId());  
            BatchInfo[] bListInfo = bulkConnection.getBatchInfoList(job.getId()).getBatchInfo();
            System.out.println("Numbe of batches is " + bListInfo.length);
            int numberOfBatchesForQueryExtract = 0;

            for(int ib=1; ib < bListInfo.length; ib++)
            {       
                BatchInfo info = bListInfo[ib];
                numberOfBatchesForQueryExtract++;

                String[] queryResults = null;

                for(int i=0; i<10000; i++) 
                {
                    Thread.sleep(30000); //30 sec
                    info = bulkConnection.getBatchInfo(job.getId(), info.getId());

                    if (info.getState() == BatchStateEnum.Completed) 
                    {
                        QueryResultList list = bulkConnection.getQueryResultList(job.getId(),info.getId());             
                        queryResults = list.getResult();
                        break;
                    } 
                    else if (info.getState() == BatchStateEnum.Failed) 
                    {
                        System.out.println("-------------- failed ----------" + info);                  
                        break;
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        System.out.println("-------------- waiting ----------"  + info);               
                    }
                }

                if (queryResults != null) 
                {
                    for (String resultId : queryResults) 
                    {
                        InputStream resultStream = bulkConnection.getQueryResultStream(job.getId(), info.getId(), resultId);
                        String fileNameCreated = createFileName(job.getId(), info.getId(),convertInputStreamToString(resultStream));
                        //System.out.println("Data extracted successfully into CVS file");
                        System.out.println("Filename " + fileNameCreated + ", No of rows in the file is " + countLines(fileNameCreated));
                    }
                }               
            }
            System.out.println("Number of batches created with chunkSize 2000 is" + numberOfBatchesForQueryExtract);
            } catch (AsyncApiException aae) {
                aae.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                ie.printStackTrace();
            }         
    }

    public String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream)
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        String line; 
        String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        boolean flag = false;
        try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"UTF8"));

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(flag? newLine: "").append(line);
                flag = true;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    public String createFileName(String jobId, String batchId, String dataAsString) 
    {
        String namePrefix = "SFBulkExtract";
        String nameSuffix = ".csv";
        String fileSeperator = "/";
        String fFileName = namePrefix + "_" + jobId + "_" + batchId +  nameSuffix;
        createFile(dataAsString,fFileName);
        return fFileName;
    }

    //Create the CVS file
    private void createFile(String dataAsString, String fFileName) 
    { 
        String fFileNameString = fFileName;
        OutputStream outFile = null;
        try {
                File oFile = new File(fFileNameString);
                if (oFile.exists()) 
                {
                    boolean deleteFileSucceeded = oFile.delete(); 
                    if (! deleteFileSucceeded) 
                    {
                        throw new IOException("Unable to delete file");
                    }
                }
                outFile = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fFileNameString));
                outFile.write(dataAsString.getBytes());
                outFile.flush();
            }catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }catch(IOException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                if(outFile != null)
                    try {
                        outFile.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }                
            }    
    }

    public static int countLines(String filename)  
    {
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));

            byte[] c = new byte[1024];
            int count = 0;
            int readChars = 0;
            boolean empty = true;
            while ((readChars = is.read(c)) != -1) {
                empty = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < readChars; ++i) {
                    if (c[i] == '\n') {
                        ++count;
                    }
                }
            }
            return (count == 0 && !empty) ? 1 : count;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that I have found the solution. Close the bulk job at the end of the processing.

Keep a count of how many batches are extracted, for example in the variable "finalBatchCount"
Now once all the batches are read, just before closing the Bulk Query Job, call the "bulkConnection.getBatchInfoList(job.getId()).getBatchInfo().length" again, and if this is less then "finalBatchCount", then get the records from the rest of the batches.
Once all the batches are read, close the Bulk Query Job

Looping this way will make sure that all the batches have been read. Attached is the code for reference

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import com.sforce.async.*;
import com.sforce.soap.partner.PartnerConnection;
import com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException;
import com.sforce.ws.ConnectorConfig;

public class BulkQueryDirect {


public static void main(String[] args)
  throws AsyncApiException, ConnectionException, IOException {
    BulkQueryDirect exampleQuery = new BulkQueryDirect();
    System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
    BulkConnection bulkConnection = exampleQuery.login();
    bulkConnection.addHeader("Sforce-Enable-PKChunking","chunkSize=200");
    exampleQuery.doBulkQuery(bulkConnection);
}


public BulkConnection login() {

      String userName = "abc@abc.com";
      String passWord = "passwordSecuritytoken";
      String url = "https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/32.0";
      BulkConnection _bulkConnection = null;
      try {

            ConnectorConfig partnerConfig = new ConnectorConfig();
            partnerConfig.setUsername(userName);
            partnerConfig.setPassword(passWord);
            partnerConfig.setAuthEndpoint(url);
            new PartnerConnection(partnerConfig);
            ConnectorConfig config = new ConnectorConfig();
            config.setSessionId(partnerConfig.getSessionId());
            String soapEndpoint = partnerConfig.getServiceEndpoint();
            String apiVersion = "32.0";
            String restEndpoint = soapEndpoint.substring(0, soapEndpoint.indexOf("Soap/"))
                + "async/" + apiVersion;
            config.setRestEndpoint(restEndpoint);
            config.setCompression(true);
            config.setTraceMessage(false);
            _bulkConnection = new BulkConnection(config);
      } catch (AsyncApiException aae) {
        aae.printStackTrace();
      } catch (ConnectionException ce) {
        ce.printStackTrace();
      }
      return _bulkConnection;
    }



public void doBulkQuery(BulkConnection bulkConnection) {

      try {

        int finalBatchCount=0;

        JobInfo job = new JobInfo();
        job.setObject("tmpTest__c");


        job.setOperation(OperationEnum.query);
        job.setConcurrencyMode(ConcurrencyMode.Parallel);
        job.setContentType(ContentType.CSV);

        job = bulkConnection.createJob(job);
        assert job.getId() != null;
        System.out.println("Job id is " + job.getId());

        job = bulkConnection.getJobStatus(job.getId());

        String query = "SELECT Name, Id FROM tmpTest__c";
        ByteArrayInputStream bout = new ByteArrayInputStream(query.getBytes()); 
        bulkConnection.createBatchFromStream(job, bout);

        BatchInfo[] bListInfo = bulkConnection.getBatchInfoList(job.getId()).getBatchInfo();

        while(bListInfo.length < 2)
            bListInfo = bulkConnection.getBatchInfoList(job.getId()).getBatchInfo();

        System.out.println("Numbe of batches is " + bListInfo.length);
        int numberOfBatchesForQueryExtract = 0;
        int numberOfRecordsExtracted = 0;

        for(int ib=1; ib < bListInfo.length; ib++)
        {   
            finalBatchCount++;
            BatchInfo info = bListInfo[ib];
            numberOfBatchesForQueryExtract++;

            String[] queryResults = null;

            for(int i=0; i<10000; i++) 
            {
                info = bulkConnection.getBatchInfo(job.getId(), info.getId());

                if (info.getState() == BatchStateEnum.Completed) 
                {
                    QueryResultList list = bulkConnection.getQueryResultList(job.getId(),info.getId());             
                    queryResults = list.getResult();
                    break;
                } 
                else if (info.getState() == BatchStateEnum.Failed) 
                {
                    System.out.println("-------------- failed ----------" + info);                  
                    break;
                } 
                else 
                {
                    System.out.println("-------------- waiting ----------"  + info);               
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Batch " + ib + " data is");
            if (queryResults != null) 
            {
                for (String resultId : queryResults) 
                {
                    InputStream resultStream = bulkConnection.getQueryResultStream(job.getId(), info.getId(), resultId);
                    BufferedReader lineReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resultStream,"UTF8"));
                    String lineString = null;
                    while((lineString = lineReader.readLine()) != null) 
                    {
                        System.out.println("lineString : " + lineString);
                        numberOfRecordsExtracted++;
                    }
                }
            }               
        }



        while(finalBatchCount < (bulkConnection.getBatchInfoList(job.getId()).getBatchInfo().length -1))
        {
            bListInfo = bulkConnection.getBatchInfoList(job.getId()).getBatchInfo();

            for(int ib=finalBatchCount; ib < bListInfo.length; ib++)
            {   
                finalBatchCount++;
                BatchInfo info = bListInfo[ib];
                numberOfBatchesForQueryExtract++;

                String[] queryResults = null;

                for(int i=0; i<10000; i++) 
                {
                    info = bulkConnection.getBatchInfo(job.getId(), info.getId());

                    if (info.getState() == BatchStateEnum.Completed) 
                    {
                        QueryResultList list = bulkConnection.getQueryResultList(job.getId(),info.getId());             
                        queryResults = list.getResult();
                        break;
                    } 
                    else if (info.getState() == BatchStateEnum.Failed) 
                    {
                        System.out.println("-------------- failed ----------" + info);                  
                        break;
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        System.out.println("-------------- waiting ----------"  + info);               
                    }
                }

                System.out.println("Batch " + ib + " data is");
                if (queryResults != null) 
                {
                    for (String resultId : queryResults) 
                    {
                        InputStream resultStream = bulkConnection.getQueryResultStream(job.getId(), info.getId(), resultId);
                        BufferedReader lineReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resultStream,"UTF8"));
                        String lineString = null;
                        while((lineString = lineReader.readLine()) != null) 
                        {
                            System.out.println("lineString : " + lineString);
                            numberOfRecordsExtracted++;
                        }
                    }
                } 
            }
        }
        bulkConnection.closeJob(job.getId());
        System.out.println("Number of batches created with chunkSize 2000 is " + numberOfBatchesForQueryExtract);
        System.out.println("Number of total records extracted is " + numberOfRecordsExtracted);
        System.out.println("Final Total Batch Count is " + finalBatchCount);
        System.out.println("BatchList length is " + bulkConnection.getBatchInfoList(job.getId()).getBatchInfo().length);
        } catch (AsyncApiException aae) {
            aae.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }         
}

public String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream)
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    String line; 
    String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    boolean flag = false;
    try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"UTF8"));

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(flag? newLine: "").append(line);
            flag = true;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result.toString();
}


public static int countLines(String filename)  
{
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));

        byte[] c = new byte[1024];
        int count = 0;
        int readChars = 0;
        boolean empty = true;
        while ((readChars = is.read(c)) != -1) {
            empty = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < readChars; ++i) {
                if (c[i] == '\n') {
                    ++count;
                }
            }
        }
        return (count == 0 && !empty) ? 1 : count;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait until the chunking is complete before closing the job.  The first batch will create all of the chunked batches.  Poll this batch's state until it is `NotProcessed`.  Then it is safe to close the job and let each of the automatically created batches complete.